# How to tell if the user is accessing the website using Mobile Phone vs Computer

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a MVC application written in C# that supports Mobile view. I would like to record the stats on the number of users accessing the website from Mobile Phone (can be any phone) vs Computer(assuming PC/Mac), is there any way to do this?

Additional info: I need to display this stats to the users on the website.

Comment: Check the agent string that is already being logged by IIS. You don't have to do change anything in your code, just check the IIS logs

Comment: But I need to display the stats to the users (on the website itself)

Comment: This is a different thing. Once you process the logs, store the statistics somewhere and display them. All sites do this periodically, eg with a job. If you don't want to write this yourself, use Google Analytics and display a mashup

Comment: Panagiotis Kanavos beat me to it, I was going to recommend Google Analytics.  Just add a little JavaScript to the pages and you can see quite a bit of data about the traffic on the site, including what type of devices are being used.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/121280/how-do-i-detect-what-browser-is-used-to-access-my-site

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos can you show me where the log is?

Answer (score -1):

HttpCapabilitiesBase.IsMobileDevice

Gets a value indicating whether the browser is a recognized mobile device. (Source - [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.httpcapabilitiesbase.ismobiledevice%28v=vs.110%29.aspx))