# Browser Detection via JS for Safari 5

Tags: javascript, extjs

How can I check if the user's current browser is Safari 5?

**Update**

We have a check on our site that displays a "Browser not supported" message if the user is using an older browser.  Currently our error is showing up for the latest Safari and it shouldn't be.

Comment: Wait, stop, *why* are you doing this?  You should never check *for the browser*, you should check **for the feature you want to use**.

Comment: Indeed. (Almost) all these browser sniffing scripts test against the User Agent string, which can be *very* easily spoofed in Safari (so it pretends it is another browser) and the workaround that you wanted doesn´t pop in. Also read http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/12/29/feature-detection-is-not-browser-detection/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Browser Detection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/100898/browser-detection)

Comment: @NickCraver https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/Undetectables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See:

[jsBrowsersDetect](http://www.virtualsecrets.com/misc_imgs/javascript/jsBrowsersDetect-demo.html)

Or

[Browser detect](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/detect.html)

***But that is not a good practice***, it is always best, however, to avoid browser specific code entirely where possible. The JQuery `$.support` property (if you want) is available for detection of support for particular features rather than relying on browser name and version.

Answer (score 3):

**If** you indeed want to do this, you can check the User Agent along the same lines Ext uses to do it.

A snippet from Ext.js:

```
    ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase(),
    check = function(r){
        return r.test(ua);
    },
    DOC = document,
    isStrict = DOC.compatMode == "CSS1Compat",
    isOpera = check(/opera/),
    isChrome = check(/\bchrome\b/),
    isWebKit = check(/webkit/),
    isSafari = !isChrome && check(/safari/),
    isSafari2 = isSafari && check(/applewebkit\/4/), // unique to Safari 2
    isSafari3 = isSafari && check(/version\/3/),
    isSafari4 = isSafari && check(/version\/4/),
```

I'm guessing for Safari 5 you could write a similar test where *version* would be 5, though I did not check what Safari 5's User Agent string looks like myself.