# browser detection in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to show a different webpage when i open my website in IE6 and below version.

Need to show `fbrowser.html` file when my website opens in IE6 and below versions.

Please suggest!!

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=browser+detection+in+javascript and http://www.quirksmode.org/js/detect.html

Comment: A well designed site using feature detection and a good fallback strategy doesn't need to detect the browser. How will you deal with browsers you don't recognise?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In head:

```
<!--[if lte IE 6]>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=fbrowser.html">
<![endif]-->
```

Sorry, no javascript needed.

Comment: that's interesting - what is doing the parsing and interpretation there?

Comment: If i m right it should be <!--[if lte IE 6]>, see missing > in end

Comment: @user859955 these are conditional comments, which are used only by IE. Doing it like this hides the content from other browsers.

Comment: Yup it is working now. but i need to do it for all my html pages. pasting this code is in all the pages is the only solution fopr this? or is there any way to redirect to the fbrowser.html when the domain name opens? And also it should not only for ie 6, it is for ie6 and lower ie versions

Comment: This syntax uses `lte` which means "less than or equal" so it detects all IE versions 6 and below. Problem solved! But if you want to detect IE earlier than during the page load, you might be better off detecting the browser on the server side. What platform are you using?

Comment: it is fully static website. html

Comment: Then all you can do is put this code in every html document, yes.

Comment: THANK YOU! Ugh I've been looking for this script all day long

Answer (score 1):

You could consider using http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2999361/1101070) answer, you can try somethiing like the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // <![CDATA[
    var BrowserCheck = Class.create({
        initialize: function () {
            var userAgent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
            this.version = (userAgent.match(/.+(?:rv|it|ra|ie)[\/: ]([\d.]+)/) || [])[1];
            this.safari = /webkit/.test(userAgent) && !/chrome/.test(userAgent);
            this.opera = /opera/.test(userAgent);
            this.msie = /msie/.test(userAgent) && !/opera/.test(userAgent);
            this.mozilla = /mozilla/.test(userAgent) && !/(compatible|webkit)/.test(userAgent);
            this.chrome = /chrome/.test(userAgent);
        }
    });    
    // ]]>
</script>
```